# Verifying that a grammar is strong LL(2)

Tags: computer-science, theory, grammar, formal-languages

Problem 19.5 of Sudkamp's *Languages and Machines* asks the reader to verify that the grammar

```
G : S' -> S##
    S  -> aSa | bSb | λ
```

is strong `LL(2)`. The `FIRST` and `FOLLOW` sets for the variable `S` are computed using Algorithm 19.5.1 (p. 583, 3rd ed.):

```
FIRST(2)(S)   = {λ,aa,bb,ab,ba}

FOLLOW(2)(S)  = {##,a#,b#,aa,bb,ab,ba}
```

It is clear that the length-2 lookahead sets for the `S` rules will not partition the length-2 lookahead set for `S`, due to the rule `S -> λ`, which gives rise to the length-2 lookahead set consisting of `FOLLOW(2)(S)`:

```
LA(2)(S)        = {##,a#,b#,aa,bb,ab,ba}

LA(2)(S -> aSa) = {a#,aa,ab}
LA(2)(S -> bSb) = {b#,bb,ba}
LA(2)(S -> λ)   = {##,a#,b#,aa,bb,ab,ba}
```

Now it is possible that I have made an error in the computation of the `FIRST`, `FOLLOW`, or `LA(2)` sets for `G`. However, I'm fairly confident that I have executed the algorithm correctly. In particular, I can revert to their definitions:

```
FIRST(2)(S)  = trunc(2)({x : S =>* x AND x IN Σ*})
             = trunc(2)({uu^R : u IN {a,b}^*})
             = {λ,aa,bb,ab,ba}

FOLLOW(2)(S) = trunc(2)({x : S' =>* uSv AND x IN FIRST(2)(v)})
             = trunc(2)({x : x IN FIRST(2)({a,b}^*{##})})
             = trunc(2)({##,a#,b#,aa,bb,ab,ba})
             = {##,a#,b#,aa,bb,ab,ba}
```

Now the question is: why is the grammar strong `LL(2)`. If the length-2 lookahead sets for the `S` rules do not partition the length-2 lookahead set for `S`, then the grammar should *not* be strong `LL(2)`. But I can't reach the conclusion expected by the book. What am I not understanding?

Comment: I did the calculations using the [algorithms I gave to my students](http://www.suigeneris.org/UCABTI/Analisis%20Sintactico%20Descendente%20Predictivo.html), and I obtained the same results you got. Find an errata or contact the author.

Comment: I might do that. The algorithms you gave to your students are similar to Sudkamp's. I found an alternative set of algorithms and obtained the same results again. I'll look at the definition later and see if I can prove that the grammar is or isn't LL(2). Thanks for checking, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. The grammar `G` given above is not strong `LL(2)`. To see this, recall the definition of a strong `LL(k)` grammar. A grammar `G` is `LL(k)` for some `k > 0` if, whenever there are two leftmost derivations

```
S =>* u1Av1 => u1xv1 =>* uzw1          S =>* u2Av2 => u2yv2 =>* u2zw2
```

where `ui,wi IN Σ*` for `i IN {1,2}`, and `|z| = k`, then `x = y`. Consider the following leftmost derivations in the grammar `G` above:

```
S =>* aaSaa##  (u1 = aa, v1 = aa##)    S =>* baSab##   (u2 = ba, v2 = ab##)
  =>1 aaaa##   (x = λ)                   =>1 baaSaab## (y = aSa)
  =>* aaaA##   (z = aa, w1 = aa##)       =>* baaaab##  (z = aa, w2 = ab##)
```

The derivations satisfy the conditions of the definition of a strong `LL(2)` grammar. However, `λ \= aSa`, and consequently `G` is not strong `LL(2)`.

Clearly we can build many leftmost derivations that demonstrate that `G` is not strong `LL(2)`. But there are several other reasons that `G` is not strong `LL(2)`. For instance, it is obvious that `G` cannot be recongized by a deterministic pushdown automata, because there is no way to determine when to begin removing elements from the stack.

Comment: I was debating whether to post this solution in the answers section, or edit the original post. If someone can provide a better solution, I'll accept their answer.